# Class vector c++ issue

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm having some trouble with vector class. For some reason, yet to be found :P, I can't insert any objects to my vector. I've tried vector, map, deque, etc, but they all have the same weird result.

The object that I want stored is a class with 2 std::string in it. Here's some code to explain my point:

```
vector<DnsAddress> * dnss = new vector<DnsAddress>;
for(int i = 0; i < ns.size(); i++){
   DnsAddress dn;
   dn.SetRecord1(record1);
   dn.SetRecord2(record2);
   cout<<dn.GetRecord1()<<" : "<<dn.GetRecord2()<<endl; //this works, so it is inserting  info to the object
   dnss->push_back(dn);//this is where it begins to fail...
   cout<<dnss->at(i).GetRecord1()<<" : "<<dnss->at(i).GetRecord2()<<endl;//doesn't work

   DnsAddress a = dnss->at(0);//this way doesn't work either...
   cout<<"dns: "<<a.GetRecord1()<<endl;
}
```

I'm sure there must be a rookie mistake.. I hate when those happen.. They consume me some time to find out.

Can someone give a hand with this?

I appreciate it :)

To claify:
There are no errors... It works without problem... but the info in the vector gets counted(.size() function tells me the number of inserted objects) but when you try to access it, nothing is shown... But no error is raised

This is class DnsAdress:

```
class DnsAddress {
public:
    DnsAddress();
    DnsAddress(const DnsAddress& orig);
    virtual ~DnsAddress();
    void SetRecord2(string record2);
    string GetRecord2() const;
    void SetRecord1(string record1);
    string GetRecord1() const;
private:
    string record1;
    string record2;

};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Do you get a compiler error?

Comment: What does the `DnsAddress` class look like?

Comment: Problem #1:  Allocating a `std::vector` on the heap, then using a raw pointer to own it, is assuredly Not A Good Idea.  What is wrong with `std::vector<DnsAddress> dnss;`?  Explicit memory management leads to memory management bugs, memory management bugs lead to pain.

Comment: It is probably due to the copy constructuor, or lack thereof in the DnsAddress class

Comment: -1, *doesn't work* is not a good explanation of what is happening, be explicit on what the issue is: *this does not compile with error <error message>* or *I expect this behavior, but the result is that* (Note, I am aware that this has no effect on the reputation, I am raising the point so that in the future you don't make the same mistakes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll bet your DnsAddress class needs a copy constructor.  This effectively gets invoked when you call push_back on a vector of non-pointer elements.

Edit: Looks like you do have a copy constructor.  Actually if you just deleted the copy constructor, the default one would work fine.  If you still want to implement it manually, you'll need to assign record1 and record2 to to orig.record1 and orig.record2 in your copy constructor implementation.

Comment: There are no errors... It works without problem... but the info in the vector gets counted(.size() function tells me the number of insert objects) but when you try to access it, nothing is shown... But no error is raised

Comment: :P All I needed was to delete the copy constructor.. well :P
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess since you didn't show your class `DnsAddress` or tell us what the error was.

My guess:

- Your class doesn't have a copy constructor (compile time error) or
- The copy constructor isn't making a correct copy (run time misbehavior).

Comment: Or the compiler-generated copy constructor is doing something like copying a raw pointer, leading to potential behavior like double-freeing memory.

Comment: @pedrop: "There are no errors": Rookie mistake. There are always errors. Always. You still haven't shown us your class definition, the implementation of your copy constructor, or the behavior that made you start this topic. Please amend your post with this information; without that information all we can do is guess.